# Add a set to existing set

Tags: python, set, intersection

My goal here is to get the intersection from all the sets in a_list.
What my error is, how to add the values to a_set.

```
a_set = set()
for i in range(len(a_list)-1):
    a_set.add(a_list[i] & a_list[i+1])
```

where:
a_list is list of sets filled with numbers.
**a_list = [{224, 225, 3, 42, 108, 45, 78, 173, 115, 23, 221, 222, 191}, {2, 67, 6, 171, 109, 79, 222}, {160, 2, 222, 184}, {225, 2, 4, 76, 45, 16, 222, 223}]**

Error:
a_set.add(a_list[i] & a_list[i+1])
TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you try to a add a set to a set.
This can not be done - `unhashable type: 'set'`
The code below does what you are looking for - it adds the intersection set memebers to the final set.

```
a_list = [{224, 225, 3, 42, 108, 45, 78, 173, 115, 23, 221, 222, 191}, {2, 67, 6, 171, 109, 79, 222}, {160, 2, 222, 184}, {225, 2, 4, 76, 45, 16, 222, 223}]
u = set.intersection(*a_list)
print(u)
```

output

```
{222}
```

Comment: This does not make an intersection from all sets. The output is supposed to be 222.

Comment: @eirikurbernharðsson Code was fixed.